# How do I add this condition in this and make it optimal?

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

The question link is: http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/431/C

> Quite recently a creative student Lesha had a lecture on trees. After
>   the lecture Lesha was inspired and came up with the tree of his own
>   which he called a k-tree.
>
> A k-tree is an infinite rooted tree where:
>
> - each vertex has exactly k children;
> - each edge has some weight;
> - if we look at the edges that goes from some vertex to its children (exactly
>     k edges), then their weights will equal 1, 2, 3, ..., k.
>
> The picture below shows a part of a 3-tree.
>
> [image]
>
> As soon as Dima, a good friend of Lesha, found out about the tree, he
>   immediately wondered: "How many paths of total weight n (the sum of
>   all weights of the edges in the path) are there, starting from the
>   root of a k-tree and also containing at least one edge of weight at
>   least d?". Help Dima find an answer to his question. As the number of
>   ways can be rather large, print it modulo 1000000007 (10^9 + 7). (Open
>   the question link above for a picture of the mentioned tree)
>
> **Input**
>   A single line contains three space-separated integers: n, k and
>   d (1 ≤ n, k ≤ 100; 1 ≤ d ≤ k).
>
> **Output**
>   Print a single integer — the answer to the problem modulo
>   1000000007 (10^9 + 7).

So, I tried to develop a recursive solution for the same. However, I am not able to add the constraint to make sure the edge of weight atleast `d` should be present. How can I do that? Here is my recursive function:

```
void calc(int present, int total,int k) // Here, present is initialised to 0.
                                        // total is equal to n that is reqd.
                                        // k is the value in the question
{
    if (total == present)
    {
        ans++;
        ans = ans%val;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for ( int i = 1; i <= k; i++ )
        {
            if (present+i <= total)
                return calc(present+i,total,k);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is this? C? Java?

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following arguments to your the function - **d** and whether you have achieved the constraint that one of these edges is at least `d`.

```
void calc(int present, int total,int k, int d, bool atleastd)
{
```

Change your constraint to increment only if `atleastd`.

```
    if (total == present && atleastd)
    {
        ans++;
        ans = ans%val;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for ( int i = 1; i <= k; i++ )
        {
            if (present+i <= total)
```

When you recursively call your function, pass whether `atleastd` has already been achieved before, **or** if you have just satisfied this constraint (`i >= d`).

```
                calc(present+i,total,k,d,atleastd || i >= d);
```

In addition, I removed the `return` in the previous line. Otherwise, the code will only test 1 possible path - a path where all weights == 1.

```
        }
    }
}
```

I assume that `ans` and `val` are globals, `ans` is the answer to the problem, initialized to 0, and `val` is the modulo = 1000000007.

---

Finally, while this solution might solve small test cases, where `n <= 15`, it will be too slow for n = 100.

To solve for n = 100, I suggest to learn about [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) and [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). I will leave this as an exercise for you.

Comment: Not that it would matter for `n >> 0`, but checking that there isn't room for d any more would cut off several recursions. - Somehow this is related to the number of (restricted by max. component) partitions of an integer, combined with permutation, for which there are direct formulas.

Comment: The problem as posed on codeforces only requires an `O(n^2)` algorithm. Actually, `O(n^3)` is probably fast enough as well. A good DP solution can solve it in `O(n)` time. @laune while some related problems have simple formulas, many simple problems, with only 1 or 2 additional constraints, can become much harder problems without direct formulas, and in some cases, even turns a problem solvable in P time, into an NP-hard problem. Rather than making a comment implying there is a direct formula, I suggest you first try to come up with such a formula.

Comment: Rather than suggesting that this can be solved for n = 100 using memoization and dynamic programming I humbly  suggest that you post a program doing just that. :-)

Comment: @laune do you think it's in the best interest of OP (and stack overflow in general) to hand out complete programming exercise solutions on a silver platter?

Comment: @janos If you think that my last comment was meant seriously: please catch up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_device. And: how do you interpret `:-)`?

Comment: @ronalchn, though your logic seems to be completely correct but somehow it doesn't gives the correct answer on the sample test cases. Though I wouldn't want you to give me the complete code, but just tell me, if their is a possibility of my logic (which you corrected further) is wrong in the first place?

Comment: @rohansingh, the bug is the return that you had in your code. I didn't notice the return in there. I've removed it from the answer.